Pass NodeJS CLI options to Phusion Passenger (--env-file)
Since NodeJS v20.6.0, node supports an --env-file .env option. The .env file will be parsed into process.env. This reduces the need to depend on third-party modules like dotenv.
I am serving my Node apps with Phusion Passenger and httpd. I can't seem to find a way to pass the --env-file argument to Node when invoked via passenger. I have tried using the PassengerAppStartCommand to do something like /usr/local/bin/node --env-file /path/to/env/file /path/to/app/index.js; this does spawn node and launches the app (and I can curl localhost:3000 to get it) but it isn't being served by Passenger/Apache.
Is it possible to pass Node CLI options to node when it is invoked by Passenger?
